# Session control Various controllers at the same page in Symfony 2?

Tags: model-view-controller, session, symfony, controllers

i'm trying to control the session to forbid the access to some pages of my web app. The way is simple, a boolean session variable. The thing is there's one page for every action, but, i think is not elegant at all to ask in every action if the user is logged or not. How can i do this elegantly in a MVC architecture? It looks crappy this way. I was thinking that there is a parent action that redirects to the final one, the one that renders the page, is it right? maybe i could make the check there.

```
public function createAction(Request $request){
        $sess = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        if ($sess->get('logged') == true) {
        // ---- ACTION CODE GOES HERE ---- //
        }
}
```

Comment: 6 questions ... 0 accepted answers ... :-/

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony2, if the sections of the site that need authorization are under the same path, you can use the access_control section in the security configuration:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/secured/area, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

You can find more ways to secure your app in the [book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-specific-url-patterns)